# What does "entwined like minks" suggest?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in the book Circe by Madeline Miller which was:

> Certainly, from the moment of my brother’s birth, they were entwined like minks.

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mink)
"mink" refers either to a mammal or its fur. But what does that have to do with "entwining"? Can it be that mink-fur entwines easily?

Comment: While we’re waiting for someone to write a proper answer, does this picture of sleeping entwined minks help? https://masonabwlab.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/sleeping-babies.jpg?w=510

Comment: photos of cute baby animals sleeping always help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a **simile** - a figure of speech involving the comparison of one thing with another thing of a different kind, used to make a description more emphatic or vivid (e.g. as brave as a lion ). (Def from google)

Here, mink is referring to the animal, not the fur.

The sentence is just comparing "them" to two minks. Although I don't know enough about minks to say whether they are particularly well known for being "entwined" together, I can imagine two minks being good at this, since they are very thin flexible creatures (hence their uses to kill pest animals such as rats, as they can fit through small holes). You can certainly picture two such creatures twisted up together with ease.

[image: Cute picture of a mink[1]]

In my opinion, otters would be a better example to use, since they are known for mating for life, or rabbits, which are known for their procreation, but both are overused, so I assume that's why the author has picked a different animal.

Comment: A comment left by Colleen (right around the time you were leaving your answer, I think) shows that minks indeed entwine while sleeping.

Comment: You are correct! I'm not sure how common this is though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that they were like mink kits (babies) - cuddled up or playing together, looking cute, but with sharp teeth and claws.

See the later sentence:

> They loved to sneer at me behind their ermine paws.

Ermine being a stoat, especially when in its white winter coat.

> Though they may look like cute pets, ermines, or short-tailed weasels,
>   are some of the fiercest little predators in Alaska.

http://www.alaskakids.org/index.cfm/cool%20critters/Featured%20Critters/Small%20Mammals/2617